# Disabling the buttons for different Users Logins

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014

First of all, I will explain what happens as a process; when the admin logs in with username and the password, access will be granted and I have used a global variation which carries the username into every form. Hope this helps for my problem.

My login code is working fine:

```
try
{
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(" Select * from Login_users where USER_NAME=@USER_NAM and PASSWORD=@PASSWOR", conn);
    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("USER_NAM", txtusername.Text.ToString()));
    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("PASSWOR", txtpassword.Text.ToString()));
    string UserType = null;
    SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    bool rowfound = reader.HasRows;
    if (rowfound)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            UserType = reader[2].ToString().Trim();

            if (UserType == "ADMIN")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome ", "Admin Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Admin_StockControl frm = new Admin_StockControl();
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else if (UserType == "STOCK_CON")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome ", "User Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Cashier frm = new Cashier();
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Invalid User Or Password ", "Login ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

This is my Newuser table from the sql server database: with examples

```
ID |    UserType   | User_Name | Password | Create_Date
..................................................
1       ADMIN          sam          123       5/5/17
2       STOCK_CON      kage         456       6/5/17
```

---------------MY ISSUE-----------------
ADMIN will be able to create a new user from the MainMenu. By clicking the button tested as "Create_new user". This is the button which should be hidden for STOCK_CON. in other-wards, i need to invisible the a button named "bunifuFlatButton3" for "STOCK_CON" and make it visible for "ADMIN".

This is my code not functioning, I don't know how it works but I tried with this code:

```
private void Admin_Menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(" Select * from New_User where User_Name=@USER_ID and Password=@PASS", conn);
    bool rowfound = reader.HasRows;
    string UserType = null;
    SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    if (rowfound)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            UserType = reader["User_Type"].ToString().Trim();

            if (UserType == "ADMIN")
            {
                bunifuFlatButton3.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (UserType == "STOCK_CON")
            {
                bunifuFlatButton3.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_...my code not functioning_" - Please state what is not functioning, do you get an exception ? what is the exception message ? That said, calling `reader.HasRows` before calling `selectCommand.ExecuteReader` is probably the source of your problem, as it does not make any sense to check for rows before the command has been executed

Comment: also, `UserType == "Administrator"` is inconsistent with `UserType == "ADMIN"` in your first example.

Comment: the error says::Cannot use local variable 'reader' before it is declared

Comment: Why not use windows credential for normal users and SQL credentials for admin.

Comment: i am sorry i edited my post changing the UserType == "Administrator" to UserType == "ADMIN" ,,

Comment: I wouldn't bother about the buttons when the passwords are stored insecurely and anyone can steal the admin's password. In Windows, you already know who the user is and which groups he belongs to. All you have to do is check if the user belongs to a specific group. ASP.NET has secure authentication and authorization mechanisms too. The IPrincipal interface, from which all user classes derive, already contains the [IPrincipal.IsInRole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.isinrole(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: Another serious problem - hiding a button doesn't mean it's not there and can't be made visible again by any automation, accessibility, testing application that sends the appropriate Windows message to the application.  You need to check priviledges and disable functionality in the *code* itself. Hiding the button is only a nice visual cue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris mentiond

You are calling   `reader.HasRows;` prop before `SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();` just like the error says: `Cannot use local variable 'reader' before it is declared`

Try this

First you need to make sure your connection object (`conn`) is properly initilized

```
 //intilize sql connection
 SqlConnection conn=// method that creates your connection string

 SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(" Select * from New_User where  
  User_Name=@USER_ID and Password=@PASS", conn);   
  //add parametars if not added (i've added "sam" and "123" just for example, you should change this to strings that user types when login"
  selectCommand.Parametars.AddWithValue("@USER_ID","sam"); 
  selectCommand.Parametars.AddWithValue("@PASS","123");     
  string UserType = "";
  //make sure to open connection before calling ExecuteReader()
  conn.Open();
  SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
            UserType = reader["User_Type"].ToString();  //you don't need Trim also
            if (UserType == "ADMIN")
            {
                bunifuFlatButton3.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (UserType == "STOCK_CON")
            {
                bunifuFlatButton3.Visible = false;
            }
     }
```

You don't need while loop,`Read()` method returns false if there are no rows, [see here examples of how to use SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: ExecuteReader has not initiated is my error and its not working!! Please Help

Comment: open connection? checkout edited [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48443034/7517846)

Comment: i placed the open connect its fine. then this error pops up: error login System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. why do i get his

Comment: you need to modify code  do to your example, i don't know how did you set connections to database, did you do it in app.config or created some method? checkout edited [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48443034/7517846) once again, so you will just need to initialize connection to database, checkout some [Ado.Net tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoFDyt8oG0k&list=PL6n9fhu94yhX5dzHunAI2t4kE0kOuv4D7) online, we are here to provide answers  not to teach coding

Comment: thank you so much for you kind motive sir, i have mentioned in beginning of the  form code as SqlConnection conn; i have created a DBConnection class which calls as conn and also i have mentioned in the app.config about the about the database servername:

Comment: can you share code where you are calling `DBConnection` class?

Comment: public SqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null; ;
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection("data source= DESKTOP-LKEG8FM\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog= PCJ_DB ; Integrated Security=True;");

                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't Open Connection !" + ex);
            }
            return conn;
        }

Comment: but where do you call `getConnection()`?, share me that

Comment: for example you should have somwhere `SqlConnection conn=GetConnection()` if you dont have that then put it in the beggining of my answer, where i provided the comment , since you are oppening connection in `GetConnection()` method, you don't need `con.Open()` that is in my answer, but i am strongly advising not to open connection in `GetConnection()` method because you will be facing some issues later on, instead open it when needed and close afterwards, once you manege to read data, i will edit my question so and explain more

Answer (score 0):

it might be because you are calling `"bool rowfound = reader.HasRows;"` and then `SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();` by the way you do not need `if(rowfound)` the `while(reader.Read())` is enough. 
and please do something like this :

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@USER_ID", SqlDbType.Int).value = "(somthing)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PASS", SqlDbType.Int).value = "(somthing)";

    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    {
        UserType = sdr.GetString(Column Index); //<= try not to type hard string this will return the string value of the column index you enter 

            if (UserType == "Administrator")
            {
                bunifuFlatButton3.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (UserType == "StockController")

            {
                bunifuFlatButton3.Visible = false;
            }
    }
```

anyway try this and let me know if it worked as i dont really understand what part of your code is "not functioning"

Comment: thank you for the instant reply sir, i tired this now one error which says: The name 'reader' does not exist in the current context

Comment: your welcome ;), hahaha that's because you copied and pasted my code lol, the sqldatareader is : "sdr" not "reader" anymore

Comment: what does come over here "(somthing)"

Comment: txtusername.Text & txtpassword.Text

Comment: txtusername.Text; this is the login page right. i made that textbox properties modifiers as PUBLIC even though i couldn't make it. why it is not being recognized. i get an error as:  txtusername does not exsit in the current context

Comment: after replace from "(somthing)" to txtusername.text

Comment: for exemple : cmd.Parameters.Add("@USER_ID", SqlDbType.Int).value = Sam;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PASS", SqlDbType.Int).value = 123;

Comment: hope it helps, so the "somthing" is supposed to be where you let your user enter his login if it a textbox then value = textbox.text

Comment: the error you get mean that they do no exist in the method where you are trying to call them maybe pass thos texts as params or somthing